# How To Properly Update Components in a Form

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a bunch of panels in my form which display images but i have a problem with getting the images to update(load next set of images) with a click of a button. I have tried using the     `ajax="false"` method but this erases the all the variables in the form e.g(the urls used to load the images ) This is my button:

```
<div style="position : absolute; right:400px; top:1500px" >
    <p:commandButton value="Confirm" id="Confirm"  actionListener="#{con.confirmButton}" oncomplete="PF('panelP').hide()" ajax="false" />
    </div>
```

The panels and Confirm button are stored in the form like:

```
<h:form id="form">


    <p:galleria id= "ISSimage" style="position : absolute; left:50px; top:550px" value="#{con.gallery}" var="image" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313" showCaption="true">
    <p:graphicImage value="#{image}" alt="Image Description for #{image}" title="#{image}"/>
</p:galleria>

        <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <p:panel id="satImage"  style="position : absolute; right:50px; top:550px" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="400">
        <p:gmap id="satview" center="#{con.lati}, #{con.longi}" zoom="6" type="SATELLITE" style="width:600px;height:400px" model="#{con.simpleModel}"  />
    </p:panel>
    </f:view>
```

I try to store a list of all the image 
        Is there a way to properly load the next set of images with the click of the confirm button without erasing the image variables?

MY BEAN is 300 lines so i only limited to showing the relevant parts . here it is:
  public void confirmButton(ActionEvent actionEvent){

```
    //setting Next Image

    //add the point depending on which panels are open then reset the panel booelan values
    gallery = new ArrayList<String>();
    candidates = new ArrayList<String>();
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    //Statement stmt1 = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    //gallery.clear();


    try{
        gallery = new ArrayList<String>();

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING,USERNAME,PASSWORD);

        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(op);
        //stmt.setString(1, oldconsole);
        //stmt.setString(2, oldconsole);
        stmt.setDouble(1, oldlati);
         stmt.executeUpdate();

        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `ISS` WHERE taskinfo__citylat = (SELECT taskinfo__citylat FROM `ISS` LIMIT ?,1)");
        int rdmnum = randomise();
        stmt.setInt(1, rdmnum);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            String issimg=rs.getString("taskinfo__link_small");
            gallery.add(issimg);
            //ADDS IMAGES TO GALLERIA
            excl_num = rs.getInt("rownum");
            excluded.add(excl_num);
            //ADDS ROWNUMBERS TO EXCLUDED ARRAY SO THEY DONT GET CALLED AGAIN.
            lati = rs.getFloat("taskinfo__citylat");
            longi = rs.getFloat("taskinfo__citylon");
            oldlati=lati;

            }
catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
public float getLati(){
    return lati;
}
public float getLongi(){
    return longi;
}

public double getOldlati(){
    return oldlati;
}
public double getOldlongi(){
    return oldlongi;
}
```

Comment: This appears to be JavaScript and not Java. If you use the correct tags, it improves your changes of getting good help.

Comment: Please add your bean and read how to create a [mcve].

Comment: What scope is your bean?

Comment: it is to load the the images into the panel

Comment: its @Sessionscoped

Comment: fixed it. my bad

Comment: Thanks for letting us know what the cause was

Comment: It was really just me making a typo in my code. lol sorry for the stress